# Logical implication and conjunction in transitive relation definition

Tags: logic, relations

In the properties of relations, the transitive relation is defined as follows:

[image]

If I read it informally, it says, "If $(a,b) \in R$ and $(b,c) \in R$, then $(a,c) \in R$

What surprised me was when the author of the [paper](http://iiitdm.ac.in/old/Faculty_Teaching/Sadagopan/pdf/Discrete/Relations.pdf) said that this definition meant,  if a relation contains just $(a, b) \in R$ but not $(b, c)$, then R is transitive.

Also, in his examples, he shows that $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_5$ are transitive relations, whereas to me, since one statement of the conjuction is false, the conjuction is false, and it doesn't proceed to the *then* part, so $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R_5$ are not transitive.

[image]

> Q. Am I reading and applying this conjunction incorrectly?

> Q. Isn't the author incorrectly translating the conjunction in the definition?

Comment: The correct reading is: if $(a,b) \in R$ but $(b,c) \notin R$, the fact that $(a,c) \notin R$ is **not** a counterexample to transitivity.

Comment: Recall  that the implication $P \to Q$ is True when $P$ is false.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p$ and $q$ be any propositions. Then the implication $p \rightarrow q$ is the proposition defined as follows:
$$
\begin{matrix} 
 p \ & q \ & p \rightarrow q \\
 F \ & F \ & T \\
 F \ & T \ & T \\
 T \ & F \ & F \\
 T \ & T \ & T
\end{matrix}
$$
The truth of $p \rightarrow q$ when $q$ is False is said to be *vacuous*.

Note that the implication is False when and only when $p$ is True but $q$ is False.

Now in your case, $p$ and $q$ are given as follows:
$$
p \ \colon \ (a, b) \in R \land (b, c) \in R
$$
and
$$
q \ \colon \ (a, c) \in R.
$$
In fact your $p$ and $q$ are the propositional functions defined by
$$
p(a, b, c) \ \colon \ (a, b) \in R \land (b, c) \in R
$$
and
$$
q(a, c) \ \colon \ (a, c) \in R.
$$

Thus for each $(a, b, c) \in R\times R \times R$, you are to show that
$$
p(a, b, c) \rightarrow q(a, c) 
$$
is True.

Hope this helps.